# Any system table or view containing the information of all databases, schemas, tables and columns in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, schema

I'm trying to find a system table or make some joins to get a table in which I can find all the columns of all the tables of all the schemas of all the databases of my server.

I'm doing this for academic purposes, so I can't use any stored procedure or function, I have to create it myself.

The point is to create a store procedure or function that receives a database name, a schema name and a table name as input parameters and throws a list of all the columns contained, but If I don't receive a table name, I should list all the columns of all the tables contained in the given database and schema. If I also don't receive a schema name as input parameter I should list all columns of all tables of all schemas in the given database.

Any ideas? As I say, I cannot use any stored procedure or function to do this.

Comment: I have looked at many system tables, I have tried forming strings and execute them with EXEC executesql but become a very mess, I guess there should be a better way to do it

Comment: I don't think any of the typical system catalog views go beyond the current database. So if you need **all** databases, you have to iterate over the databases and inspect the system catalog views in each of them

Comment: Is this iteration only possible through dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need for all the columns of all the tables in the current database accessable by currect user:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx

To find the same from all databases, you have to connect to each of the databases and then access the system view.

If you connect as the dba user, you will have access to all tables in all schemas.

Comment: thank you but it is not the point, I need to be able to run it from any other database different from the one I want to get the schemas, tables and columns

Comment: then you need db-links to the other databases from your currect database to access them.

Comment: How do I declare and use a db-link? Can it be used as transact-SQL or should it use dynamic SQL? I have never heard about db-links before

Comment: you probably don't need dynamic sql. you probably don't even need db-link to query a different database in the same server. you simply prefix the table name with the database name in the query as in `database.table`.

Comment: yes, but, as I get (at least) the database, (and possibly) the schema and table names as parameters... I dont perceive another way to form my query other than forming a string and then execute it.

Comment: With so many variablity you will have to compose the sql statement before executing ig.

Answer (score 0):

There are tables in the sys schema which may be of interest.  sys.databases, sys.schemas, sys.tables, sys.columns  all of which can be easily joined together and filtered to your needs.

`sp_msforeachdb 'SELECT t.name FROM [?].sys.schemas s 
    INNER JOIN [?].sys.tables t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN [?].sys.columns c ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]';`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that those tables only work for the database I'm currently in. I need to be able to run the procedure or function for any database different from the one the procedure or function is stored.

Comment: You will need to loop through each database either by using the undocumented sp_msforeachdb or you own means.